# Linear diophantine equation of n variables.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, diophantine-equations, exponential-diophantine-equations

I know how to solve a linear Diophantine equation of 2, 3 variables. But is there a way to solve directly a linear Diophantine equation of n variables. For example using matrix?

Answer (score 3):

I guess you'll interested in the following article *[Linear Diophantine Equations](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ewgilbert/Research/GilbertPathria.pdf)* written by William J.Gilbert. It contains the following theorem.

> **Theorem**. To solve the system of linear Diophantine equations $AX=B$, unimodular row reduct $[A^t |I]$ to $[R|T]$, where $R$ is in
> row-echelon form. Then the system $AX=B$ has a integer solutions if
> and only if the system $R^tK=B$ has integer solution for $K$, and all
> the solutions of $AX=B$ are of the form $X=T^tK$.

It also contains one example and one exercise with $3$ variables. So you can compare this  with the method you know.

Comment: Thank you for your answer I will check it!